# pointer to c# function from c++

Tags: c#, функции

Необходимо вносить изменения в запускаемом файле в режиме реального времени.
Файл написан на **C#** + xna framework.
Как изменять сам файл, на лету, я знаю, но я не знаю как найти в C# приложении адрес функции.(обычно достаточно использовать GetModuleHandle и GetProcAddress)
функция появляется в процессе работы приложения.
мне нужно получить доступ к коду по адресу **FakeName.Main::Update+5CD6**.
вообще необходимо получить одно значение на которое нету статических указателей, но как раз в той части кода появляется указатель на нужный адрес. 
это всё делаю на **с++**.
Уже дня 3 ищу нормальную информацию по-этому поводу, но может быть я плохо ищу.
больше всего натыкаюсь на вызов с# функции внутри dll но мне это не подходит по-скольку приложение не должно вызывать мои функции.

Comment: Кряк пишете или чит к игре?

Comment: @VladD чит к игре террария будет изменять количество итема к максимальному, он уже работает нужно только найти адресс, чтобы он был статическим, для себя. до этого уже сделал чит для fallout 2, но ведь это никому не нужно (т.е. я действительно делаю это для себя)

Comment: А почему адрес процедуры статический? В .NET процедуры компилируются на лету.

Comment: @VladD он не статический. дело в общем так: в некой функции есть указатель на другой нужный указатель, ни в каком другом месте больше нету указателя на нужный указатель, по-этому нужно получить адрес этой функции, (указатель в ней тоже оказался не статическим хоть и прописывается в коде как статический (в асме) )

Comment: @VladD мне нужно только получить статический адрес нужного указателя, а для этого нужно узнать где находится динамическая функция..к примеру Cheat engine это умеет

Comment: Смотрите. В файле программы на .NET нету машинного кода, там есть только кроссплатформенный ассемблер (IL), который компилируется на лету JIT-компиляцией. То есть, функции создаются в рантайме. При этом, понятно, область памяти для функций — это куча, и функции попадают туда в случайном порядке. Поэтому я не забивался бы на фиксированные смещения в вашем случае.

Comment: @VladD ... эта функция единственное место, в которой есть указатель на нужную переменную, и я знаю что адрес функции не статический , по-этому и нужно её именно искать , это возможно, так как Cheat Engine спокойно каждый раз находит нужный адрес зная имя функции и находя её адрес. я же не знаю как получить адрес на динамическую функцию созданною в c#